# Updating mongodb document angular-meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, angular-meteor

I'm trying to update a current document in an ng-repeat list that each document has it's own form in the ng-repeat.

I'm trying to get mongo to update the document when I hit the update button and like I have it now it works but I'm not sure if this is the best way.

Here's my controller:

```js
$scope.showPreloader = true;

$scope.subscribe('events', () => {
    $scope.showPreloader = false;
});

$scope.helpers({
    events: function() {
        return Events.find({});
    }
});

$scope.save = function() {
    Events.insert($scope.newEvent);
    $scope.newEvent = undefined;
    console.log('saved');
};

$scope.update = function(event) {
    Events.update({
        _id: event._id
    }, {
        $set: {
            name: event.name,
            description: event.description,
            background: event.background
        }
    }, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('unable to update the event: ' + error);
        } else {
            console.log('Done!' + data);
        }
    });
};
```

as you can see here, in the `$scope.update` function, I'm setting `$set` all the parameters I want to update, but I'm looking for a way to make it automatically so I don't have to type each parameter to be update, something like in the `$scope.save` function `Events.insert($scope.newEvent);`.

Here's the form:

```js
<div>
    <div class="spinner" ng-show="showPreloader"></div>
    <div ng-repeat="event in events | orderBy: '-createdAt'" class="wow fadeInUp col-md-6 events-grid-background" ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url({{event.background}})'}">
        <div class="grid-content" ng-init="event.edit = true" ng-show="event.edit" layout="column" layout-wrap layout-align="center center">
            <h2 class="blue grid-title">{{event.name}}</h2>
            <p class="bold">{{event.description | limitTo: 100}}...</p>
            <a ui-sref="event-detail({eventId: event._id})" class="blue-hover bold">&#161;Leer M&#225;s!</a>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-if="isAdmin" ng-click="event.edit = !event.edit"><strong>Editar</strong></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-if="isAdmin" ng-click="remove(event)"><strong>Delete</strong></button>
        </div>

        <!-- event edit form -->
        <div ng-if="isAdmin" class="grid-content" ng-show="!event.edit">
            <form name="form" novalidate>
                <label class="white" for="name">T&#237;tulo</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="event.name" required>
                <label class="white" for="description">Descripci&#243;n</label>
                <textarea id="description" name="description" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="event.description" required></textarea>
                <label class="white" for="background">Imagen</label>
                <input id="background" name="background" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="event.background" required>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-if="isAdmin" ng-click="event.edit = !event.edit; update(event)"><strong>Guardar</strong></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-if="isAdmin" ng-click="event.edit = !event.edit"><strong>Cancelar</strong></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this without having to set one by one the parameters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use:

```
var e = event;
var id = event.id;
delete e._id
Events.update({_id: id}, {
  $set: e
}, function(err, result) {
  .. handle result
});
```